# How to rebuild an old plugin for Jira 7?

Tags: maven, plugins, jira, jira-plugin

I have a plugin which is custom built for Jira 6.x and I want to make the same plugin to work for Jira 7.x. What are the ways to do this?
Say the only resource I have is the .jar plugin file which has all the information about classes, dependencies, related to old version of jira. 
If I make changes to the pom.xml file and upload the addon to jira, will it work with Jira 7.x?

Error From Log: 
`/rest/issueNav/1/issueTable [c.atlassian.ozymandias.SafePluginPointAccess] A LinkageError indicates that plugin code was compiled with outdated versions.Unable to run plugin code because of 'java.lang.AbstractMethodError - null'.`

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There are API changes which requires source code changes, some details here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/preparing-for-jira-7-0/jira-7-0-api-changes

Comment: I did check the documentation, I am wondering if there is an alternate way of making the plugin work since I do not have the source code. It was custom built by someone else prior to me.

Comment: Without the source code, if you have the copyright to the plugin, decompiling might be the only way to go. It won't be easy though as you will need to reverse engineer it and then build it on your own.

Comment: It took me quite some time to get hold of the source code, but finally I was successful in retrieving it from the third-party. 
**My approach** for this rebuild is to create a skeleton plugin and then add all classes and interfaces necessary to trace the same logic. Once this is done, I would check the dependencies to ensure all variables are set and available to rebuild a package. Am I missing anything else here?

Comment: That make sense, it is how I would approach it too. Look for the pom.xml file to see if any libraries are used other than Atlassian's SDK.